# How to load app on iphone?

Tags: applications, xcode, iphone

I have iPhone and I have developed an app in xcode 7 I want to it to install and run into iphone but how to do that ? Like android load .apk file on phone and from phone just double click and you done. Some what like procedure is there in iphone ?

Comment: Have you read Apple's documentation - which built don't you understand - google for `xcode run app on phone` gives this as first hit

Comment: @Mark I got it....from xcode only automatically install when I connect my phone (when choose my_phone as target).